# Mule ESB - integration testing - REST endpoint - using MuleClient

Tags: java, rest, mule, esb, mule-component

I am new to mule ESB. I am trying to do integration test for a rest endpoint exposed via mule flow.
The following code, hits POST REST endpoint but how can we say the rest params and http method (get or post or delete etc.,) :

```
    MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
    String payload = "foo";
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:5000/rest/resource", payload, properties);
```

Should we set any thing in the payload or properties (Map) that is passed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into source code, I am able to set Http method with following properties.,

Example Get Request:

```
    MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("Content-type", "text/plain");
    properties.put("Accept", "text/plain");
    properties.put("http.method", "GET");

    MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:5000/rest/resource?param1=268", null, properties);
```

Example Post request:

```
    MuleClient client = new MuleClient(muleContext);
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    properties.put("http.method", "POST");

    String payload = "{...json here...}";

    MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:5000/rest/resource", payload, properties);
```

Hope it helps someone else.,